# Difference between static IP and elastic IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, ip

With Amazon's EC2, to assign an IP address I create an "Elastic IP", however it seems to just give me a static IP address. What is the difference between a static IP and an elastic IP? Or is it the same and just part of AWS's branding?

Comment: Is it really static and not someone that you assign dynamically in the UI? Clouds are not always as static as servers - so they may refer to the fact that you can ask for htem and release them in a moments notice.

Comment: [Elastic IP Adresses docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Amazon Guides are always a good reference to understand better the entire infraestructure. In [Amazon EC2 Elastic IP Addresses](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346) you can read:

> *Elastic IP addresses are static IP addresses designed for dynamic cloud computing. Unlike traditional static IP addresses, however,
>   Elastic IP addresses allow you to mask instance or availability zone
>   failures by programmatically remapping your public IP addresses to any
>   instance associated with your account. Rather than waiting on a data
>   technician to reconfigure or replace your host, or waiting for DNS to
>   propagate to all of your customers, Amazon EC2 enables you to engineer
>   around problems with your instance or software by programmatically
>   remapping your Elastic IP address to a replacement instance.*

Comment: Why do they call it "elastic"?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) says:
>A user can create, launch, and terminate server-instances as needed, paying by the second for active servers – hence the term "elastic"

So the dynamics payment is the reason.